# How do I show character development in a subtle and natural way?

Tags: character-development

I'm writing a 4-6 book series, with a female in her late 20s as the protagonist. It's in first person, and I'm struggling to think of how to show her development without having to spell it out and it seeming unrealistic.
She's starting out as shy with low self esteem, a bit self-involved. I don't want her to end up perfect as I want it to be realistic, and I'm struggling with how to show the development subtly over time.

Comment: Step one would be set a starting and ending point between each book. on how the character is

Comment: After you have done Step One (above comment) and you know where the MC needs to be at the climax of each story **do not write 4-6 books at once, Write 1 book** as if it is the *only* book in which readers will meet this character. Each story needs a character arc from A-Z, never a *partial* arc from A-B, or B-C.

Comment: And one of the great ways to show character is through choices they make. You could show her making choices she would not have made earlier on.